# How to use named mutex at linux?

Tags: linux, posix, mutex

I'd like to use named mutex at linux for multi process.

I searched at google and find some APIs.
But, it's hard to break out the coding.
I found two apis and it looks set name and be shared between processes.

```
pthread_mutexattr_setname_np
pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&mtx_attr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
```

Could somebody give me hint or example?

Comment: Why do you want to use a "named mutex"?  Your `pthread_mutexattr_setname_np` appears to be IBM-specific and for debugging.  And the `PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED` is for mutexes allocated _in_ shared memory; the mutex doesn't somehow reach across processes on its own.  Are you sure you don't want a [POSIX semaphore](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/semaphore.h.html)?

Comment: probably the closest to named mutexes is named POSIX semaphores: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Semaphores.html#Semaphores If you need to use the pthreads api, you could create the mutex in shared memory using `pthread_mutex_init`: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html or http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shmget.2.html

Comment: POSIX semaphores are great, and extremely similar to WinApi Semaphores. But WinAPI has Mutex that is very useful in certain situations. The main feature it has is that it is robust, so if the owning process dies, exactly one waiting process can acquire it, and detect that it was abandoned. This seems very hard to implement using pthreads, though you can look at https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/pal/src/synchobj/mutex.cpp (part of a big .NET/WinAPI emulation framework).